# Is cooking with fruit liqueur comparable to cooking with fruit juice?

Tags: fruit, alcohol, liqueur

I had some cranberries and blueberries that were past their prime, so to preserve them I made them into a liqueur. However I'm not much of an alcohol drinker, so I was thinking of using this liqueur for cooking. How does one use fruit liqueur in cooking? Will there be a noticeable taste difference from using the juice of these fruits once the alcohol has evaporated?

Comment: You could always use it in ways that aren't actually "cooked". For example, you can soak berries in it and use it as a filling for cakes/cupcakes.

Comment: The alcohol won't evaporate. The idea that alcohol added to cooked dishes is imprecise, I don't have the table at hand for evaporation percentage vs time but at least half of it stays forever.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry rumtscho that is incorrect. Alcohol will completely evaporate, what does stay "forever" is the flavor the spirit will impart but chemically ethyl is evaporative, to test my posit try wiping some rubbing or high proof vodka on a glass surface and you can actually watch it evaporate. The "How" depends on the recipe in e.g., deserts usually @ the end or in a finishing sauce. You could also make a chutney or in a marinade.

Cheers!

EDG

Comment: Actually I'm afraid you're incorrect. The idea that alcohol completely evaporates during anything but relatively long cooking is a myth, as shown by this study: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1556354, summarised here: http://whatscookingamerica.net/Q-A/AlcoholCooking.htm. Even a 2.5 hour braise will leave around 5% of the alcohol behind; flambeeing will leave 75%.